# keep reading from txt file and save the strings java

Tags: java, file

I want the best way to keep reading lines from txt file and save them to a variables for later processing 
i know how to code it but i cannot think the best way for saving the strings somewhere,for example  variables or something else and after i reached at the end to process them
edit:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader(filename));

    while(in.hasNextLine()){
        answer=in.nextLine();
        if (answer.contains("-")) {
            temp=answer.split(":");
            value=Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);
            freq=Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);
        }

    }
```

what i want after i reached at the end of the txt file i want to compare freq values and archive them from the smallest to bigger

Comment: What do you have so far? We're happy to help with a specific problem, but we aren't going to write your code for you.

Comment: Use a `List<String>`.

Comment: Why not store in an array?

Comment: because i do not know the size of the lines, maybe there are 2 lines maybe 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it using a [scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(file object pointing at file));
List<String> listOfLines = new ArrayList<String>();
while (s.hasNext()) {
   listOfLines.add(s.next());
}
s.close();
```

but there are various ways you can do it using BufferedReaders and other java classes. It sounds like the crux of your question is about what data structure to use. You should use a list as this grows dynamically. Arrays are no go for you unless you know the number of lines in the file upfront

Update:

If you want to add val and freq then i would create another class.

```
class StuffHolder {
   private final String val;
   private final String freq;

   public StuffHolder(String val, String freq) { 
      this.val = val;
      this.feq = freq;
   }
   //plus some getters

}
```

and then would update your List to be

```
List<StuffHolder> listOfLines = new ArrayList<StuffHolder>();
```

I\m sure you can think of a better name than StuffHolder ;)

if you re looking are trying to count frequences then you might be better off using a map if val is a key. Val could be the key in the map and then you could increment the value by one every time you find an instance of val

Comment: how can i add 2 words which must me together to the List<String> listOfLines = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: @user1778339 see update to my answer

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to read a whole file is to use [the Files convenience methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29), for example:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("path/to/your/file"),
                             Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

You can then work on the list and do what you need with the lines.

Comment: +1 didnt know about this method to readAllLines

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the lines separately you can use arrays, otherwise just keep adding the content of the file to a string variable.

But you should specify what you want to do with the content so we can help you.

Comment: each line has 2 words separated with : i want to save the 2 words and then sort them from the lower to higher value of the word after :   namely freq. the two words freq and value go together. must not get separate